# filename returning as a directory for php unlink

Tags: php, unlink

I keep getting the error message

> "Is a directory
> Error String: unlink(../testDir/..)"

when the following code hits the unlink line; this is meant to cycle through another directory and delete any files older than 10 minutes in this scenario.

```
$path = '../directory';
if ($handle = opendir($path)) {
    while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) { 
        $filelastmodified = filemtime($path .'/'. $file);
        if((time() - $filelastmodified) > 600){ //older than 10 minutes
            unlink($path .'/'. $file);
        }
    }
    closedir($handle); 
}
```

Comment: I think the variable `$file` is null in the loop, can you add a `var_dump($file)` before the line starts with `if((time() - $..` to see what its value?

Comment: That was my suspicion as well, so I had each iteration of $file echo out on it's own, and they showed up as expected, but when I echoed out the path and file as it would be sent to unlink, only the path (../directory/..) shows up